# CRM 2016: Save and Route Incident

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

CRM 2016 introduces a new feature: Save and Route (an Incident). The new Save & Route button combines the multiple steps required in earlier versions of CRM.

Now I want to perform programatically this action (for an incident also) either in js or in custom activity based on some conditions.

Any pointers to show me how can I do that?